# How to get access to Spiked Chain?

Tags: weapons, pathfinder-2e, pathfinder-society

[Unconventional Weaponry](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=72) only gives access to uncommon weapons associated with an ancestry.

How do I get [Spiked Chain](https://2e.aonprd.com/Weapons.aspx?ID=60) in Pathfinder Society? (*"my previous DM allowed it"* won't work there)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Via Boons

@willuwontu's answer is correct and guaranteed, just not available to all classes; it is also theoretically possible to get access to Spiked Chains via boons. Spiked Chains are marked as being a standard PFS option (meaning normal rules apply to it), and the [rules for PFS options state](https://2e.aonprd.com/PFS.aspx):

> Specific boons—such as from the Achievement Points system or Chronicle Sheets—can also grant access to these options.

One such boon is "Avid Collector - Core Rulebook", which contains the Spiked Chain (see [this blog post on Paizo.com](https://paizo.com/community/blog/v5748dyo6shbg?Achievement-Points-and-Free-RPG-Day)). It costs 20 AcP. Credit to @Ifusaso and @YogoZuno for finding this!

Comment: The "Avid Collector - Core Rulebook" (that I've only found by accessing my login at https://paizo.com/ >Organized Play>Boons) grants "Select an uncommon item from a curated list of Pathfinder Core Rulebook options; this PC gains access to it. " for 20 AcP. AcP is granted in allotments of about 1, 4, or 12 upon completion of adventures according to the 3rd party website Organized Play Foundation. Unfortunately I've been unable to verify that Spike Chain is on the "curated list", nor even find said list.

Answer (score 15):

## Be a [Cleric](https://2e.aonprd.com/Classes.aspx?ID=5) of [Luhar](https://2e.aonprd.com/Deities.aspx?ID=216), or [Zon-Kuthon](https://2e.aonprd.com/Deities.aspx?ID=20)

[Cleric](https://2e.aonprd.com/Classes.aspx?ID=5)'s have the following proficiency:

> Trained in the favored weapon of your deity. **If your deity’s favored weapon is uncommon, you also gain access to that weapon**.

Since Spiked Chain is the favored weapon of Luhar and Zon-Kuthon, if you're a cleric of either, you gain access to it.